# NodeJS module executing user script with external function not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, workflow, external

I am quite new to nodeJS.

I am using the nodeJS module [node-workflow](https://github.com/joyent/node-workflow)

Basically, this module is an orchestrator that takes a custom javascript script (=workflow definition), then serialize it and store it in a REDIS db (for example), and execute on-demand later on by the **node-workflow** module.

A workflow definition is composed of task, like this:

```
var my_external_module = require('my_external_module');

var workflow = module.exports = {
        name: 'Workflow Test',
        chain: [{
                    name: 'TASK 1',
                    timeout: 30,
                    retry: 1,
                    body: function(job, cb) {
                        // Execute external function
                        my_external_module.hello("Monkey");
                        return cb(null)
                    },
                },
...
```

First I put my function my_external_module.hello() in a .js file beside the workflow script.
When I run the **node-workflow** module I get the following error:

> Error initializing runner:
>
> [ReferenceError: my_external_module is not defined]

So I have created a module **my_external_module**,
and in: **./node_modules/my_external_module/index.js**

```
    module.exports = {
        hello: function(name) {
            console.log("Hello, " + name);
        }
    };
```

When I run the **node-workflow** module I get the same error:

> Error initializing runner:
>
> [ReferenceError: my_external_module is not defined]

It seems that the **require(...)** shall stands in one of the .js files of the **node-workflow** module, so I would have to hack one of the files of the module, but it is a bit dirty.

Is there something I missed?

Or is there a way to define a $PATH like in Python in order to my function to be accessible from everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You have to require it as:

```
var my_external_module = require('./my_external_module');
```

Notice the `./` this means Node should search for a file like `./my_external_module.js`

If you omit the `./` Node looks at the installed modules on (usually) `node_modules` directory

Comment: Thanx Michelem for your answer. Unfortunatly  it doesnt work.
I tried to include a standard npm module:
`var markdown = require('markdown').markdown;`

and call it: 
`console.log(markdown.toHTML('Un paragraphe en **markdown** !'));`

but it doesnt work also.

In the examples I have, the npm module **restify** has been used in the tasks body and its working well, because it is also include in the **node-workflow** module

Comment: Your external file should be in the same directory of your app file not inside node_modules impossible it doesn't work

Comment: Indeed, if I open a node shell and call:
`var my_external_module = require('./my_external_module');
my_external_module.hello("Monkey");`
then it is working

The problem is that my script is serialized (without the **require** calls) by the **node-workflow** module and run later on. And it seems that the scope is not the same, so the require are not here anymore